# Machine Learning - test set with fewer features than the train set

Tags: python, machine-learning

guys.
I was developing an ML model and I got a doubt. Let's assume that my train data has the following data:

### ID | Animal | Age | Habitat

### 0  | Fish   | 2   | Sea

### 1  | Hawk   | 1   | Mountain

### 2  | Fish   | 3   | Sea

### 3  | Snake  | 4   | Forest

If I apply One-hot Encoding, it will generate the following matrix:

### ID | Animal_Fish | Animal_Hawk | Animal_Snake | Age | ...

### 0  | 1           | 0           | 0            | 2   | ...

### 1  | 0           | 1           | 0            | 1   | ...

### 2  | 1           | 0           | 0            | 3   | ...

### 3  | 0           | 0           | 1            | 4   | ...

That's beautiful and work in most of the cases. But, what if my test set contains fewer (or more) features than the train set? What if my test set doesn't contain "Fish"? It will generate one less category.

Can you guys help me how can I manage this kind of problem?

Thank you

Comment: The Naive Bayes algorithm has a case for this.  You just ignore the "missing values" and when you have extra data, your not modeled on it anyway

Comment: Then the `Fish` feature should have zeroes going all the way down.

Comment: 0's aren't always the same as missing values

Comment: The test set should generally be a subset of your input dataset and have the same features. The same is true for your live data that you want your algorithm to make predictions from. Some algorithms have more tolerance for missing features than others (e.g. random forest), however depending on the importance of the feature it will affect the prediction performance.

Comment: @Adam Good point, but I don't think it matters in this case. If your training set has 3 classes of some discrete variable (e.g. "fish," "dog," and "cat") while your test set only has two (e.g. "fish" and "dog"), would it not be easiest to add a "cat" feature to your test set with zeroes? If you didn't "see" a cat in your test set, but *did* in your training set, then that cat feature should be accounted for. The absence of a group in either data set doesn't preclude that set's not having that group's feature.

Comment: How are you splitting into train and test? Are the two datasets separate and you load them individually, or do you load your full dataset then use something like `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`?

Comment: @not_a_robot In this case, how could I add the "cat" feature in my test set using scikit-learn?

Comment: @not_a_robot About how I am splitting the data: I'm thinking about train a model using a dataset and deploy it as a web service. So, the user could use it easily, by passing a sample to be predicted. For example:

1 | Hawk | 1 | Mountain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have your train and test sets completely separate. Here's a minimal example of how you might automatically add "missing" features to a given dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

# Made-up training dataset
train = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish', 'fish', 'bear'],
                      'age': [12, 13, 31, 12, 12, 32, 90]})

# Made-up test dataset (notice how two classes are from train are missing entirely)
test = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['fish', 'fish', 'dog'],
                      'age': [15, 62, 1]})

# Discrete column to be one-hot-encoded
col = 'animal'

# Create dummy variables for each level of `col`
train_animal_dummies = pd.get_dummies(train[col], prefix=col)
train = train.join(train_animal_dummies)

test_animal_dummies = pd.get_dummies(test[col], prefix=col)
test = test.join(test_animal_dummies)

# Find the difference in columns between the two datasets
# This will work in trivial case, but if you want to limit to just one feature
# use this: f = lambda c: col in c; feature_difference = set(filter(f, train)) - set(filter(f, test))
feature_difference = set(train) - set(test)

# create zero-filled matrix where the rows are equal to the number
# of row in `test` and columns equal the number of categories missing (i.e. set difference 
# between relevant `train` and `test` columns
feature_difference_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((test.shape[0], len(feature_difference))),
                                     columns=list(feature_difference))

# add "missing" features back to `test
test = test.join(feature_difference_df)
```

`test` goes from this:

```
   age animal  animal_dog  animal_fish
0   15   fish         0.0          1.0
1   62   fish         0.0          1.0
2    1    dog         1.0          0.0
```

To this:

```
   age animal  animal_dog  animal_fish  animal_cat  animal_bear
0   15   fish         0.0          1.0         0.0          0.0
1   62   fish         0.0          1.0         0.0          0.0
2    1    dog         1.0          0.0         0.0          0.0
```

Assuming each row (each animal) can only be **one** animal, it's fine for us to add an `animal_bear` feature (a sort-of "is-a-bear" test/feature) because of the assumption that if there *were* any bears in `test`, that information would have been accounted for in the `animal` column.

As a rule of thumb, it's a good idea to try to account for all possible features (i.e. all possible values of `animal`, for example) when building/training a model. As mentioned in the comments, some methods are better at handling missing data than others, but if you can do it all from the outset, that's probably a good idea. Now, that would be tough to do if you're accepting free-text input (as the number of possible inputs is never-ending).

Comment: Great explanation, @not_a_robot. Thank you. I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

The train set determines what features you can use for recognition. If you're lucky, your recognizer will just ignore unknown features (I believe `NaiveBayes` does), otherwise you'll get an error. So save the set of feature names you created during training, and use them during testing/recognition.

Some recognizers will treat a missing binary feature the same as a zero value. I believe this is what the NLTK's `NaiveBayesClassifier` does, but other engines might have different semantics. So for binary present/absent features, I would write my feature extraction function to always put the same keys in the feature dictionary.